# A question regarding Hermite polynomials and exponential operators $\exp[e^{x^2/2}p(\frac{d}{dx})e^{-x^2/2}]f(x)$

Tags: operators, mathematics

Is it possible to express $$\exp\left[\mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}\right] f(x)$$ as an integral transform or something similar? $p(x)$ is a polynomial.
$$\exp\left[\mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}\right]f(x) = \int k(x,t)f(t)\,dt.$$
By expanding the exponential, I get
$$\exp\left[\mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)e^{-x^2/2}\right] f(x) = f(x) + \mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}f(x) + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2} f(x) + \ldots,$$
which has operator coefficients similar to [Hermite polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html).

Comment: You are sure you want the mathematicians' not the physicists' [polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) ?

Comment: Yes, this expression appeared in my calculation. Nonetheless, it would also be interesting to know the expression for the physicists polynomials.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: Moving to https://mathoverflow.net/q/452838/478084